# How to make facebook crawler loads page dynamic title / description?

Tags: reactjs, facebook, sharethis

My little application is written in reactjs, on a page it will update title / description based on the real object that user selected like [this photo](http://xphoto.devcovery.com/#/photo/42745768315). The new title and description are display correctly but when sharing on fb, the values are not loaded correctly (the value is from old html templated) - go to facebook and paste the url or use [fb debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/)  the values are from static html page.

Have anyone had this issue and have "fixed" it ?

Thanks for any recommendation !

Answer (score 1):

Facebook ignores JavaScript, so dynamic OG tags are not possible. You can solve this with Server Side Rendering or https://prerender.io/, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass as parameter in url (abc.com?title=awesome&desc=flower), and in og tags use that parameter to make dynamic.